# Regular Expression regex pattern in javascript for inputs with commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input scenario where the pattern of input is as follows:

```
var location = /^[a-z]+\s*[a-z]*,\s*[a-z]+\s*([^,]?[a-z]+)*$/i;
```

My input are of the following allowed types:

- Los Angeles,CA
- Los Angeles, CA         (has space(s) between string text)
- Los Angeles,CA,USA
- Los Angeles, CA,USA     (has space(s) between string text)
- Los Angeles, CA, USA    (has space(s) between string text and maybe after the end text)

The following input types( the ones with the extra , are not passing the test:

- Los Angeles,CA,USA
- Los Angeles, CA,USA     (has space(s) between string text)
- Los Angeles, CA, USA    (has space(s) between string text and maybe after the end text)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

And yes, I'm new to regex and js.

Complete code used for testing:

```
if (str.match(locationstring)){             
console.log("Match pattern str!");          
type = 2;       
}else{          
alert("No match str!");             
return;         
}
```

Comment: Try `/^[\s\S]+,[\s\S]+([^,]?[\s\S]+)*$/` and see if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp can only match a , at one position - exactyl where the comma in the regexp is. SO it's obvious that it won'T match strings that include multiple ;)

This regexp will match all your test cases (and, in contrast to yours, match cities that don'T have spaces in their names  - those exists, you know? ^^):

`/^\w+(\s*\w+)?\s*,\s*\w+\s*(,\s*\w+)?$/i?`

(It still does not match contries or states that include whistespace - if it should, tell me.

Comment: Yea, this allows inputs like "Seattle, " or "Seattle,", Seattle,WA," etc.

Comment: It does (actually, no, `Seattle,` shopuld not be matched, unless I made some mistake). Shpouldn't it? Then what should be matched and what shouldn't?

Comment: Seattle,<space>  seems to be allowed thru

Comment: that's really strange. `\w+` (the second one) shouldn't be able to match the space, but is non-optional... Can you post the complete code you use to test the regexp?

Comment: My bad! pattern is correct. Sorry, about that. It was being rewritten elsewhere.! Than you for  all your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
var location = /^[a-z]+\s*[a-z]*,\s*[a-z]+\s*([^,]?[a-z]+)*$/i;
                                              ^^^^
```

Here, you're explicitly disallowing any commata (with a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)). Every string that has more than one comma is out with that rule.

It seems you actually want to allow a comma followed by optional whitespace in that place:

```
var location = /^[a-z]+\s*[a-z]*,\s*[a-z]+(,\s*[a-z]+)*$/i;
```

Comment: Thank You! I was under the impression that ^ at start denoted start of symbol. This soln solved my initial problem, but still lets thru inputs like "Seattle," and Seattle, ,".